# Place text in the centre and middle of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a project where text from an array iterates line by line, which works.

I would like the text to appear in the centre of the webpage and also the middle

I am new to Javascript + HTMl

Here is the code so far which iterates the text in the array.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('#container');

var splittedText = [
  "This is line one", "This is line two", "This is line three", "This is line four"
];
var clone = [...splittedText]
var content = []

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
  if (content.length >= 1) content = []
  var element = clone.shift();
  content.push(element + "<br/>");
  if (clone[0] == "") {
    content.push("<br/>");
    clone.shift();
  }
  container.innerHTML = content.join('')
  if (clone.length === 0) {
    clone = [...splittedText]
    content = []
  }
}, 3000)
```

```css
#container {
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 400%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Please edit this with a more specific question. It's not clear at all what is or isn't working right now, or what you're actually asking.

Comment: apologies @WOUNDEDStevenJones just edited OP

Comment: You will need to use CSS to achieve what you want. Perhaps enclose the text in a `div` or a `span` with classes and use CSS to style those.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wmfb3xp6/

Comment: That's it @ChrisG, much appreciated...am i ok to incorporate the CSS inline in the html?(newbie)

Comment: Sure, just put it in a `<style>`.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG ..just updated op with a variation of original question.

Comment: You're welcome, but why did you edit the solution into the question?

Comment: DOH, Im not being very clear here. I updated the code as I've changed the question slightly. Your code (thanks again) has the text appearing in the middle of the screen...but it seems to appear at the top of the screen...I would like it to appear in the centre of the screen..hope that makes sense?

Comment: @paul did you have a look at my answer? It displays the text int the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

We need to use some tags instead of loose string so that we can style things. I think this should get you started:

```js
const body = document.body;
const splittedText = [
  "This is line one",
  "This is line two",
  "This is line three",
  "This is line four"
];

let clone = [...splittedText];

setInterval(function() {
  const elSpan = document.createElement("span");
  const elBr = document.createElement("br");
  if (clone.length === 0) {
    clone = [...splittedText];

    let child = body.lastElementChild;

    while (child) {
      body.removeChild(child);
      child = body.lastElementChild;
    }
  }
  const text = clone.shift();

  elSpan.innerHTML = text;
  body.appendChild(elSpan);
  body.appendChild(elBr);

  if (text == "") {
    body.appendChild(elBr);
    clone.shift();
  }
}, 3000);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```